# Every surjective homomorphism is integral.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that every surjective ring homomorphism is integral, i.e., $f: R \longrightarrow S$ is integral, where $f$ is onto

We define $s$ is integral over $R$ if there exists a poly $p(x) \in R[x]$ such that $p(s) = 0$. Besides, $f$ is integral if every $s \in S$ is integral over $R$.

It seems to me that I need to find a proper polynomial, which should be trivial, but I just cannot get one.

Any hint would be great! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a *monic* polynomial.

But now that's easy: the $R$-module structure on $S$ is given by $f$ by
$$r\cdot s:=f(r)s$$
Now, for any $s\in S$, there is an $r\in R$ such that $s=f(r)$, so just take
$$p(x) = x-r$$
(meant as $1\cdot x-r\cdot 1$), that gives $p(s)=s-r\cdot 1=s-f(r)=0$.

Comment: I guess I missed the part that $S$ is an $R$-module. It is also an $R$-algebra, right? @Berci

Comment: Yes. But the notion 'integral' can be defined on modules.

Comment: You get the same if you interpret the polynomials in the $R$-algebra structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Berci